# Required library XENOMAI NOT FOUND

Tags: real-time, orocos

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration) to install orocos in my system with ubuntu 16.06, xenomai 3.0.5. But i'm getting error:

```
Orocos RTT version 2.9.0
No orocos-rtt.cmake file loaded, using default settings.See orocos-rtt.default.cmake
Detected OROCOS_TARGET environment variable. Using: xenomai
-- CMAKE_VERSION: 3.5.1
-- Found Boost Uuid in /usr/include.
-- Orocos target is xenomai
XENOMAI_INCLUDE_DIR=XENOMAI_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
XENOMAI_NATIVE_LIBRARY=XENOMAI_NATIVE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at config/LibFindMacros.cmake:74 (message):
  Required library XENOMAI NOT FOUND.

  Install the library (dev version) and try again.  If the library is already
  installed, set the XENOMAI_ROOT_DIR environment variable or use cmake to
  set the missing variables manually.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  config/FindXenomai.cmake:72 (libfind_process)
  config/check_depend.cmake:164 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:106 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/robot/orocos-toolchain/build_isolated/rtt/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'rtt': 
  Command '['/home/robot/orocos-toolchain/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/robot/orocos-toolchain/src/orocos_toolchain/rtt', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/robot/orocos-toolchain/install_isolated', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/robot/orocos-toolchain/build_isolated/rtt && /home/robot/orocos-toolchain/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/robot/orocos-toolchain/src/orocos_toolchain/rtt -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/robot/orocos-toolchain/install_isolated -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

Before this i have sucessfully installed orocos toolchIN without the xenomai kernel. But now i'm getting the error.

Comment: `XENOMAI_INCLUDE_DIR=XENOMAI_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND`

Comment: well i edited the ~/.xenomai_rc file for that like this: export XENOMAI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/xenomai/include
export XENOMAI_NATIVE_LIBRARY=/usr/xenomai/include/trank/native but still same error.